# Pipe something as the first input of a command

Tags: bash, unix, pipe

```
echo 'abc' | grep input.txt
```

This returns 'file abc not found'.
What I want to do is to find all all lines with abc.
I know I can simply write

```
grep abc input.txt
```

but what if I want to pipe the input to grep?

Comment: Could you explain *why* you want to do this? It's possible, but the appropriate technique depends on the reasoning.

Comment: To save duplicating on different answers, I'll clarify up here: are you saying that the command you want to run dynamically generates patterns, and you want to check a file against those patterns?

Comment: To save duplicating on different answers, I'll clarify up here: are you saying that the command you want to run dynamically generates patterns, and you want to check a file against those patterns? Yes!

Comment: @user2922049 Patterns, plural, or just one? It's an important distinction.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What I mean by pattern is just one word.

Comment: master stroke of guys :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use variables:

```
var="abc" && grep "$var" input.txt
```

I assume you get the keyword `abc` out of another command, then you can also run

```
grep "$(command)" input.txt
```

e.g. in your example above, that would be

```
grep "$(echo 'abc')" input.txt
```

Comment: Needs more quotes, or else the output of `command` is going to be word-split, and all but the first word emitted will be considered a filename.

Answer (score 2):

The following will read the content to search for from stdin:

```
grep -e "$(cat)" input.txt
```

As such, the behavior you requested:

```
echo "abc" | grep -e "$(cat)" input.txt
```

...will work correctly. That said, can you describe the use case? There's probably a better way to do what you're trying to accomplish.

---

Okay -- the use case was clarified in a comment elsewhere. The right tool to use isn't a pipeline but a command substitution:

```
grep -e "$(commands-to-get-the-pattern)" input.txt
```

Comment: That first command doesn't work for me, the subshell just complains: `-bash: cat: No such file or directory`. I think you don't want the `<` in there, just `"$(cat)"`.

Comment: @IMSoP You're entirely correct; I did indeed want `$(cat)`.

Answer (score 1):

you should write:

```
grep "abc" input.txt
```

If you want to pipe it:

```
cat input.txt | grep "abc"
```

This is possible as well:

```
grep "$(command)" input.txt
```

OR

```
grep `command` input.txt
```

So if you want to use `echo` command do this:

```
grep "$(echo abc)" input.txt
```

OR

```
grep `echo abc` input.txt
```

Also you can write:

```
var="abc" && grep `echo $var` input.txt
```

OR

```
var="abc" && grep $(echo $var) input.txt
```

Comment: The goal is to make `abc` be programmatically generated in this case, so this answer isn't quite on-point.

Comment: piping the answer is what our friend want...and I used simple answer as well at the top///There are lots of solutions as you know...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo 'abc' | grep -f - input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
cat input.txt | grep abc
```

grep then searches 'abc' within the piped input.

For a dynamic search pattern you can use

```
grep $(<command>) input.txt
```

with `<command>` being the command that outputs the search pattern.

Comment: I got some command to get the pattern to grep. I want to run those commands first and then use grep to grep the pattern in input.txt. I don't know what the pattern is before I run the commands. abc is just an example. I want to pipe the 'abc' part but not he file name.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this question comes about because you have a list of keywords to search for in the same file.  Here's one way you might go about it:

```
$ cat sought_words 
include
return
int dot
blah

$ cat sought_words | while read line; do echo "searching for" $line; grep -n "$line" stack_dots2.c; done
searching for include
1:#include <stdio.h>
2:#include <stdlib.h>
3:#include <string.h>
searching for return
20:      return 1;
28:  return 0;
searching for int dot
8:  int dotless_length = 30;
searching for blah
```

grepping for `"$line"` instead of just `$line` allows finding `int dot` including the space, instead of interpreting `dot` as another file name to search for `int` in.

Comment: Running a separate grep for each keyword isn't exactly efficient when they could all be done with one pass.